# Nested resource with 2-deep association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, cancancan

I'm trying to set up Active Admin so an AdminUser (logged in) can view a list of all ServiceUsers they are allocated, then click on a link next to a specific ServiceUser to see all support sessions they have created (for that specific ServiceUser).

Model:

```
class ServiceUser
  has_many :support_allocations
  has_many :admin_users, through: :support_allocations
  has_many :support_budgets

class AdminUser < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :support_allocations
  has_many :service_users, through: :support_allocations

class SupportAllocation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :admin_user
  belongs_to :service_user
  has_many :support_sessions

class SupportSession < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :invoice, optional: true
  belongs_to :support_allocation
  has_one :service_user, through: :support_allocation
  has_one :admin_user, through: :support_allocation
```

I'm guessing I need to make SupportSessions a nested resource of ServiceUser so I can follow restful principles (i.e with a route to e.g. /service_users/1/support_sessions). I've managed to nest the resource like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register SupportSession do
  belongs_to :service_user
```

But I realise that omits the crucial join table SupportAllocation. Also, it doesn't work! Error message is:

```
NoMethodError in SupportSessionsController#index
undefined method `support_sessions' for #<ServiceUser:0x00007fe6316b9030> Did you mean? support_allocations
```

Previously I could view all SupportSessions for all ServiceUsers allocated to an AdminUser by using the code:

```
ActiveAdmin.register SupportSession do
super.includes(support_allocation: [:service_user, :admin_user])
```

This issue is I'd like to work with a resource in the context of the SupportAllocation relationship between a ServiceUser and an AdminUser. So the logged in AdminUser can see an index list of all ServiceUsers they are allocated (via SupportAllocation), then move to an index list of all SupportSessions for a selected ServiceUser (from that first list).

Is a nested resource the right solution here or is there a simpler way to just have a generic SupportSession resource page that can either show SupportSessions for ALL ServiceUsers or a specific ServiceUser (by 'id' in the URL)? How do I work with this tricky two-level association with an intermediary table?

Thank you so much for your help.

Here's the code for my support_sessions.rb controller in app/admin/

```
ActiveAdmin.register SupportSession do
  menu label: 'My sessions'
  #belongs_to :support_allocation
  belongs_to :service_user

  # Eager loading to speed up queries
  includes :service_user, :admin_user, :support_allocation

  sidebar :help, priority: 0 do
    "Need help? Email us at help@example.com"
  end

  # Default sort order
  config.sort_order = 'support_sessions.date_held_asc'

  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      #super.includes :support_allocation
      super.includes(support_allocation: [:service_user, :admin_user])
      #SupportSession.includes(support_allocation: [:service_user, :admin_user])
      #super.includes :service_user, :admin_user
    end
  end

  scope :all, :default => true
  scope :invoiced
  scope :uninvoiced

  index do
    selectable_column
    column 'Date held', :date_held

    #column 'Service user', :full_name, :sortable => 'service_users.family_name' do |ss|
      #service_user = ServiceUser.find(ss.support_allocation.service_user.service_user_id).full_name
      #ss.support_allocation.service_user
    #end

    #column 'Based at', sortable: 'support_allocation.service_user.organisation.org_name' do |ss|
      #ss.support_allocation.service_user.organisation.org_name
    #end

    column 'Venue', :venue

    #column 'Support worker', :full_name, :sortable => 'admin_users.family_name' do |ss|
      #support_worker = AdminUser.find(ss.admin_user_id).full_name
      #ss.support_allocation.admin_user
    #end

    actions
  end

  permit_params(:admin_user_id, :service_user_id, :venue, :mode_of_delivery, :date_held, :time_start, :time_end, :total_breaks, :status)

  form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys

    f.inputs 'Support session details' do
      # Code to check if creating a new record or editing an existing record:
      #if f.object.new_record?

      #if current_admin_user.super_admin == false
        # Pre-select only current support worker (so no other choices)
        #f.input :admin_user, :label => 'Support worker', as: :select, collection: AdminUser.where(super_admin: 0, #id: current_admin_user.id), include_blank: false
      #else
        # Otherwise list all support workers
        #f.input :admin_user, :label => 'Support worker', as: :select, collection: AdminUser.where(super_admin: 0), include_blank: true, allow_blank: false
      #end

      #f.input :support_allocation
      #f.input :service_user, :label => 'Service user', as: :select, collection: ServiceUser.all, include_blank: true, allow_blank: false

      f.input :mode_of_delivery, as: :select, collection: SupportSession.mode_of_deliveries.keys, include_blank: true, allow_blank: false

      f.input :venue, :label => 'Venue'
      f.input :date_held, :label => 'Date held', :as => :datepicker
      f.input :time_start, :label => 'Start time'
      f.input :time_end, :label => 'End time'
      f.input :total_breaks, :label => 'Total breaks (in minutes)', :input_html => { :value => '0' }

      if current_admin_user.super_admin == false
        f.input :status, as: :select, collection: SupportSession.statuses.keys, include_blank: true, allow_blank: false
      end
    end
    f.actions
  end


end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your ActiveAdmin registrations need to be reflected the same way as they are in your models.

For example, you have:

```
ActiveAdmin.register SupportSession do
  belongs_to :service_user
```

but your `SupportSession` model is defined as:

```
class SupportSession < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_one :service_user, through: :support_allocation
  ...
```

Assuming your model is correct, the ActiveAdmin registration should also be a `has_one` relationship.

Additionally, it looks like you have not fully defined your model relationships. Your `ServiceUser` model does not have a corresponding `belongs_to` relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip on my model.

To fix my original problem I nested my SupportSession ActiveAdmin controller within the SupportAllocation:

```
ActiveAdmin.register SupportSession do
  menu label: 'My sessions'
  belongs_to :support_allocation
```

This creates a new nested route for SupportSession within the context of SupportAllocation (which defines the relationship between a ServiceUser and a SupportSession) letting me create a link (e.g. /support_allocations/2/support_sessions) from SupportAllocation directly to all SupportSessions for an individual ServiceUser, using the usual path helper:

```
actions defaults: false do |support_allocation|
  link_to 'Manage support sessions', support_allocation_support_sessions_path(support_allocation_id: support_allocation.id), class: 'member_link'
end
```